# Could not find validation handler checkCurrentPassword for current_password

Tags: php, validation, cakephp, passwords, cakephp-2.0

I am getting error like this

> Warning (512): Could not find validation handler checkCurrentPassword
>   for current_password
>   [CORE/Cake/Model/Validator/CakeValidationRule.php, line 281]

my User.php

```
public function validate_passwords() {
        return check( $this->data[$this->alias]['confirm_password'], $this->data[$this->alias]['password']);
}
```

Comment: if any one know this help me

Comment: you should show your code

Comment: you should write your controller ,view ,and model code.

Comment: The title doesn't match the warning in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not access check() like this beacause it is a protected method

for more info see : http://api.cakephp.org/3.0/class-Cake.Validation.Validation.html

don't you try something like below :

```
public function validate_passwords() {
    return array('check' => array($this->data[$this->alias]['confirm_password'], $this->data[$this->alias]['password']));
```

}

**To validate confirm_password with password add this rule:**

```
$validator->add('confirm_password', 'no-misspelling', [
    'rule' => ['compareWith', 'password'],
    'message' => 'Passwords are not equal',
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this for validate confirm_password with password

```
public function validate_passwords() 
{
     return $this->data[$this->alias]['password'] === $this->data[$this->alias]['confirm_password'];
}
```

its work for you.